# Collision of light with light

Tags: visible-light, momentum, conservation-laws

Photons have momentum. So when a light passes through another light what happens? Do they collide and conserve momentum?

If they collide they should deviate (move away from the straight line at a certain angle) from their path. But that doesn't happen in ordinary life, why?

Comment: 2 water waves can meet, interact, and then travel again on to their destination in their original form, same for EM waves (photons).

Comment: @PhysicsDave, I agree.  When I did demos in my high school physics class, I used waves on a spring.  I explicitly pointed out to the students that when two waves traveling in opposite directions meet, they interfere with each other, but an instant later, both waves continue traveling at their original speed and with their original shape as if they had never met the other wave.  They pass right through each other with each wave conserving its energy and shape.